Пишу бота, помощь в настройке кнопок
Не могу сделать так чтобы пользователь при нажатии на инлайн кнопку выполнял функцию выбора женщина или мужчина и присылал ответ от пользователя, а не бота как при обычных кейбоард кнопках или же просто сохранял данные сразу без отправления. 
Буду очень рад помощи.
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) 
def get_sport_activity(message): 
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup() 
    btn1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Заполнить свои параметры', callback_data="pr1") 
    btn2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Ваша суточная каллорийность', callback_data="kl1") 
    btn3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Показать мои данные', callback_data="show_data") 
    markup.row(btn1, btn2) 
    markup.row(btn3) 

    bot.reply_to(message, 'Привет, я бот который помогает соблюдать рацион питания и тренировок. Вот мои функции ↓ ', reply_markup=markup) 

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True) 
def callback_massage(callback): 
    if callback.data == 'pr1': 
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Введите ваш возраст:") 
        bot.register_next_step_handler(callback.message, process_age) 
    elif callback.data == 'show_data': 
        user_id = callback.message.chat.id 
        user_data = get_user_data(user_id) 
        if all(value is not None for value in user_data.values()): 
            message_text = f"Ваши данные:\n" \ 
                           f"Возраст: {user_data['age']}\n" \ 
                           f"Пол: {user_data['gender']}\n" \ 
                           f"Рост: {user_data['height']} см\n" \ 
                           f"Вес: {user_data['weight']} кг\n" \ 
                           f"Уровень физической активности: {user_data['sport_activity']}" 

            bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, message_text) 
        else: 
            bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Вы еще не заполнили свои данные.") 

    elif callback.data == 'kl1': 

        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup() 

        file = open('112m.png', 'rb') 

        bot.send_photo(callback.message.chat.id, file, reply_markup=markup) 

 

def process_age(message): 

    try: 

        markup1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup() 

        age = int(message.text) 

        btn10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Мужской', callback_data="10") 

        btn11 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Женский', callback_data="11") 

        markup1.row(btn10, btn11) 

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пожалуйста, выберите ваш пол:", reply_markup=markup1) 

        @bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True) 

        def process_command_1(callback): 

            if callback.data == '10': 

                with bot.retrieve_data(message.chat.id) as data: 

                    data["Мужской"] = message.text 

            elif callback.data == '11': 

                with bot.retrieve_data(message.chat.id) as data: 

                    data["Женский"] = message.text 

        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_gender, age) 

    except ValueError: 

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пожалуйста, введите корректный возраст.") 

        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_age) 

 

def process_gender(callback, message, age): 

    gender = message.text.lower(callback) 

    if gender in ['мужской', 'женский']: 

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Введите ваш рост в сантиметрах:") 

        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_height, age, gender) 

    else: 

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Пожалуйста, введите 'мужской' или 'женский'.") 

        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, process_gender, age)


Что-то я ничего не понял, какую кнопку, что за выбор, что куда и зачем сохранять?

@Amgarak, все просто, пользователь нажимает инлайн-кнопку и начинает выполнять функцию выбора, а затем присылает свой ответ, чтобы доказать, что он не бот, а кожаный бастард.  Времена такие настали, без инлайн-кнопки никуда..
